# Error while running checksetup.pl Bugzilla 5.0.6 Install: The regular expression you provided '^[^,]+{' is not valid

Tags: regex, perl, bugzilla

I am attempting to install Bugzilla on a Windows 10 machine using this guide:

https://bugzilla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing/windows.html#

Apache 2.4, Perl 5.28.2, and MySQL 8.0 are installed and functioning. I have installed all of the required Perl modules using the 'install-modules.pl --all' command. I can pull up the Bugzilla page, although its the plain text version.

The issue is running the checksetup.pl the last time. It checks for all installed modules, then gives me this:

```
Removing existing compiled templates...
Precompiling templates...done.
Initializing "Dependency Tree Changes" email_setting ...
Initializing "Product/Component Changes" email_setting ...
Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at Bugzilla/Install/DB.pm line 2688.
The regular expression you provided '^[^,]+{' is not valid. The error
was: Syntax error in regular expression on line 1, character 7..
```

I found the regular expression in the DB.pm file in `sub _add_password_salt_separator`. (Line 4110)

Here is the chunk of code that seems to be the problem child:

```
  my $profiles
    = $dbh->selectall_arrayref(
        "SELECT userid, cryptpassword FROM profiles WHERE ("
      . $dbh->sql_regexp("cryptpassword", "'^[^,]+{'")
      . ")");
```

I tried reloading Bugzilla to see if it was just an issue with the download or configuration, but after round 3, I still get the same error.

I tried looking up the expression and it doesn't seem to make any sense. I am not familiar with regular expressions so I don't know where to go with this issue. Any help getting this system running is appreciated.

Comment: I tried making that change and it still gave me the error: 
`The regular expression you provided '^[^,]+\{' is not valid.`

Comment: Can you just `echo "SELECT userid, cryptpassword FROM profiles WHERE (" . $dbh->sql_regexp("cryptpassword", "'^[^,]+{'") . ")"` and add the output to your question details? This will give a much clearer idea whether your string concatenation is producing a valid SQL statement. To me, the start and end quotes `'` look suspicious especially since `^` denotes the start of a string in regex.

Comment: @ikegami So is `character 7` from the error referring to `]` or `+`?

Comment: So adding `"'^[^,]+\\\\{'"` allowed it to continue but now there is another error:

`electcol_arrayref failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near [SQL Command] at Bugzilla/DB.pm line 1521`

Comment: `        Bugzilla::DB::_check_references(Bugzilla::DB::Mysql=HASH(0xb4eb848), "bug_group_map", "group_id", HASH(0xee7a610)) called at Bugzilla/DB.pm line 663
        Bugzilla::DB::bz_add_fks(Bugzilla::DB::Mysql=HASH(0xb4eb848), "bug_group_map", HASH(0xaa0a7d0), HASH(0xee7a640)) called at Bugzilla/DB.pm line 581
        Bugzilla::DB::bz_setup_foreign_keys(Bugzilla::DB::Mysql=HASH(0xb4eb848)) called at Bugzilla/Install/DB.pm line 748
        Bugzilla::Install::DB::update_table_definitions(HASH(0x2ec9590)) called at C:\bugzilla\checksetup.pl line 175`

Comment: How do I get it to output those results?

Comment: I don't think that's related.

Comment: ... Feel free to ask another Question about the problem (but we'd need to see the SQL statement, not `[SQL Command]`).

Comment: I figured out what is happening with that error. MySQL 8.0 has added GROUPS as a keyword. Now every time the install references the Groups table it throws an error. Basically, I am sitting here chasing down every error and adding backticks around the table name.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that MySQL no longer allows an unescaped `{` to be used to match a `{`.

This probably happened when MySQL started using a new regex library with better Unicode support in version 8.0.4.

In `Bugzilla/Install/DB.pm`, replace

```
"'^[^,]+{'"
```

with

```
"'^[^,]+\\\\{'"
```

I submitted a [ticket](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1611495).

---

For those curious about why so many slashes:

`$dbh->sql_regexp` expects its second argument to be SQL that generates a MySQL regex pattern.

1. The Perl string literal  `"'\\\\{"` produces the string `'\\{'`.
2. The string `'\\{'` is used as SQL code.
3. The SQL code `'\\{'` produces the string `\{`.
4. The string `\{` is used as a regex pattern.
5. The regex pattern `\{` matches a `{`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.